# InDesign CS6 and InDesign CC 2015 on Mac OS Sierra not seeing Helvetica fonts

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, mac

I have upgraded from Mac OS X El Capitan to Sierra last month, and InDesign works well, generally. CS6 is a bit slow but does load, CC 2015 loads but with PDAppFlex on opening.

I have InDesign CS6 and InDesign CC 2015 installed - and they work OK.

However, neither will recognize the Mac OS X system Helvetica font, and I don't know why.

Is this normal behavior InDesign CC 2015 and CS6? Previously I used to have no issue with that font on previous OS X installs when I used Adobe InDesign.

I have no font managers installed so that isn't be the problem.

I also have Photoshop CS6 and Helvetica works with no problems on Mac OS Sierra.
I would appreciate any advice on trying to fix this.

Comment: Not sure what the issues but I would guess a font manager would fix it. I'm planning on upgrading to Sierra this weekend so I'll let you know if it does :)

Comment: "Previously I used to have no issue with that font on previous OS X installs" - but others *did*. I personally witnessed, just last week, a simple export to PDF showing all characters in a system Helv Neue turn to Undefined Character blocks. So it might be filtered out of the available fonts on purpose.